# NSURLErrorDomain code =-1001 request getting timed out

Tags: ios, objective-c, client-server

I am developing an iOS app that should send the data collected by sensors to a server. However I am only able to send the data for 1 min after that I get a following error:

```
submit error = Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1469a9820 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xyz/abc/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xyz/abc/, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xyz/abc/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xyz/abc/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

Here is the code snippet that tries to send the data:

```
-(void)postData:(NSString*)postTo withParameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters withHeaders:(NSDictionary*)headers{
    [[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
        [request setUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, postTo]];
        [request setHeaders:headers];
        [request setParameters:parameters];
    }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"submit error = %@", error);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"submit to %@ success", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/", BASE_URL, postTo]);
        }
    }];
}
NSDictionary* headers = @{@"accept": @"application/json"};
for (int i = 0; i < sensorDataLength; i++) {
        SensorData *Obj = [SensorArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"x": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", Obj.xAxis], @"y": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", Obj.yAxis]};

        [self postData:@"abc/" withParameters:parameters withHeaders:headers];
    }
```

How can I increase the timeout interval of 60 secs?
Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://unirest.io/objective-c.html):

**Timeout**

> You can set a custom timeout value (in seconds):

```
[UNIRest timeout:2];
```

> By default the timeout is 60.